# JQuery Date Time Picker load Object Data Timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I insert a date/time picker using jquery (with start and end date + time in German format) and when this is selected the Object field is reloaded with the Grafana Dashboard with the selected timestamp (e.g. 1697407200000&to=1697493599000)?

Ideally this time format would also be in plain text German format above the Object Data e.g. 25.10.23 00:00 - 25.10.23. 23:59

Thanks a lot

```html
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="window.print()">Print complete Website</button>

<br>
<br>

<object data="https://grafana/d/test/test?0=k&1=i&2=o&3=s&4=k&orgId=1&from=1697407200000&to=1697493599000" style="height: 100%; width:100%" type="text/html">
    Grafana Dashboard
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you asked. If you have more questions about how to use jQuery datepicker you can go to [datepicker docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

This is what I did. This updates Grafana Dashboard's data attribute. You can add/remove the format date string as you wish, I took it from here [date format example](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats).

Final approach.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<button onclick="window.print()">Print complete Website</button>

<br>
<br>
<p>
    Format options:<br>
    <select id="format">
        <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
        <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
        <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
        <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
        <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
        <option value="&apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy">With text - &apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy</option>
    </select>
</p>

<object id="myObj" data=""
        style="height: 100%; width:100%" type="text/html">
    Grafana Dashboard
</object>
<label>From</label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="startDate" />
<br />
<label>To</label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="endDate" />


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataObj = "https://grafana/d/test/test?0=k&1=i&2=o&3=s&4=k&orgId=1&from={0}&to={1}&fromPlain={2}&toPlain={3}";
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["de"]);

    $("#format").on("change", function () {
        $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
        $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
    });

    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (a, b, c) {
            var now = new Date(b.currentYear, b.currentMonth, b.currentDay);
            var attrText = dataObj.replace('{0}', now.getTime());
            var attrText = attrText.replace('{2}', now.toDateString());

            var endDate = $("#endDate").datepicker('getDate');
            if (endDate != null) {
                attrText = attrText.replace('{1}', endDate.getTime());
                attrText = attrText.replace('{3}', endDate.toDateString());
            }

            $("#myObj").attr("data", attrText);
        }
    });
    

    $("#endDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (a, b, c) {
            var now = new Date(b.currentYear, b.currentMonth, b.currentDay);
            var attrText = dataObj.replace('{1}', now.getTime());
            var attrText = attrText.replace('{3}', now.toDateString());

            var startDate = $("#startDate").datepicker('getDate');
            if (startDate != null) {
                attrText = attrText.replace('{0}', startDate.getTime());
                attrText = attrText.replace('{2}', startDate.toDateString());
            }

            $("#myObj").attr("data", attrText);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I try it but got this Error Message: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setDefaults')  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["de"]);

Comment: Try to comment that line, I think it is not necessary for what you need.